# PHP cURL - HTTP GET with basic authentication 403

Tags: php, curl, get

First off, my PHP and cURL experience is a grand total of 0, so bear with my ignorance.
Anyway, I'm trying to retreice a JSON using the Seneye API:  https://api.seneye.com/api/resources/view/q/device_get

I have a basic understanding of the process, and have got all my :id and basic authentication that I need: I tested all this using https://www.hurl.it to make sure all the credentials are correct, and retrieved the full JSON.

I read around and managed to put together the following PHP

```
<?php

$username = 'addusername'; //Example entry
$password = 'addpassword'; //Example entry
$URL = 'https://api.seneye.com/v1/devices/3442?IncludeState=1'; //Actual ID code different

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$result=curl_exec($ch);

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo "HTTP CODE:: " . $status_code;

curl_close ($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);

echo "<br><br>";
print_r($json);

?>
```

But I'm receiving HTTP code 403 in return, with the message "Method not Allowed". So I can only assume there is something wrong with the way I'm using the authentication?!

Any and all help/advice appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you sure? Method Not Allowed is normally associated with a 415 code.

Comment: Also the API doc you referenced appears to suggest the username and password should be sent on the querystring rather than via an auth header

Comment: When testing in hurl.it, if I left out the basic auth, it would also return a 403 with message "Method Not Allowed".  I saw that, so tested with the URL of:  https://api.seneye.com/v1/devices/3442?IncludeState=1  and it still worked though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation at the link you provided, the URL is supposed to be in the form

```
https://api.seneye.com/v1/devices/3442?user=***&pwd=***
```

where the username and password are sent as querystring parameters, rather than in an authorisation header.

So I think your PHP code should look like this:

```
<?php

$username = 'addusername'; //Example entry
$password = 'addpassword'; //Example entry
$URL = 'https://api.seneye.com/v1/devices/3442?IncludeState=1&user='.$username.'&pwd='.$password; //Actual ID code different

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo "HTTP CODE:: " . $status_code;

curl_close ($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);

echo "<br><br>";
print_r($json);

?>
```

Note that technically this is *not* Basic Authentication as officially defined, it's a custom scheme. It's also not ideal from a security point of view because browser and servers often log the URLs which are visited, which means that the credentials end up being stored, often in plain-text, in many different places.

Comment: Sadly, this still gives me the same results as before

Comment: My mistake. This does appear to work, thank you. Any explanation for why I can use the URL without the querystring using basic authentication in hurl.it though? Also, is there any way to make this more secure? Or this a poor show on the developers of the custom scheme?

Comment: I've no idea why it would work in hurl.it, sorry. Without having any valid credentials I've no way to test it out. From the docs, it shouldn't work but possibly hurl.it does something different when it creates the request. There's nothing much you as the mere consumer of the API can do to make it more secure, apart from complain to the vendor.